# Why should we store log files and bin-log files on different path or disks in mysql

Tags: mysql, logging, space, disk

I have replication setup mysql databases....the log file location the bin-log file all are at one path that is default my data directory of mysql.

I have read that for better performance one should store them separately.

Can anyone provide me how this improves the performance. Is there is documentation available for the same. The reason why one should do so?

Answer (score 3):

Mainly because then, reads and writes can be made almost in parallel. Stored separately meaning on different disks.

[Linux and H/W optimizations for MySQL](http://www.slideshare.net/matsunobu/linux-and-hw-optimizations-for-mysql-7614520) is a nice presentation of ways to improve MySQL performance - it presents benchmarks and conclusions of when to use SSD disks and when to use SCSI disks, what kind of processors are better for what tasks.

Very good presentation, a must read for any DBA!!

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly for cases where your database write traffic is so high that a single disk volume can't keep up while writing for both data files and log files. Disks have a finite amount of throughput, and you could have a very busy database server.

But it's not likely that separating data files from binlogs will give better performance for queries, because MySQL writes to the binlog at commit time, not at query time. If your disks were too slow to keep up with the traffic, you'd see `COMMIT` become a bottleneck.

The system I currently support stores binlogs in the same directory as the datadir. The datadir is on a RAID10 volume over 12 physical drives. This has plenty of throughput to support our workload. But if we had about double our write traffic, this RAID array wouldn't be able to keep up.

You don't need to do *every* tip that someone says gives better performance, because any given tip might make no difference to *your* application's workload. You need to measure many metrics of performance and resource use, and come up with the right tuning or configuration to help the bottlenecks under your workload.

There is no magic configuration that makes everything have high performance.

Answer (score 1):

It also can be really embarrassing to have your log files fill the file system and bring the database to a halt.

Answer (score 1):

One consideration is that using a separate disk for binlogging introduces another SPOF since if MySQL cannot write the binlog it will croak the same as if it couldn't write to the data files. Otherwise, adding another disk just better separates the two tasks so that binlog writes and data file writes don't have to contend for resources. With SSDs this is much less of an issue unless you have some crazy heavy write load and are already bound by SSD performance.